# How to extract the url of an image from a JSON (LastFM API)

Tags: java, android, json

I am a beginner in the use of JSON.

So I try to extract the url of an image from a JSON reply.

Here is the code that allows me to get an Array:

```
            // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
            //String url ="http://www.google.com";
            String url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.search&album="+albumName+"&api_key=c51f8eb36bad&format=json";


            // Request a string response from the provided URL.
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                            //mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
                            Log.i("RESPONSE","Response is: "+ response);

                            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject();
                            try {
                                jsono = new JSONObject(response);
                                //String url = jsono.getString("results");


                                //Log.i("RESPONSE",url);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.d ("RESPONSE",e.getMessage());
                            }
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                            try {
                                jsonArray = jsono.getJSONObject("results").getJSONObject("albummatches").getJSONArray("album");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.d ("RESPONSE",e.getMessage());
                            }
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                                try {
                                    object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Log.i("RESPONSE",object.getString("image"));

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("RESPONSE","That didn't work!");
                }
            });
            queue.add(stringRequest);
```

And here is the structure of this part in the JSON answer:

```
    {

    "album": [
        {
            "name": "DD Y Ponle Play",
            "artist": "Jumbo",
            "id": "2528039",
            "url": "http://www.last.fm/music/Jumbo/DD+Y+Ponle+Play",
            "image": [
                {
                    "#text": "http://images.amazon.com/images/P/B00005LN6S.01._SCMZZZZZZZ_.jpg",
                    "size": "small"
                },
                {
                    "#text": "http://images.amazon.com/images/P/B00005LN6S.01._SCMZZZZZZZ_.jpg",
                    "size": "medium"
                },
                {
                    "#text": "http://images.amazon.com/images/P/B00005LN6S.01._SCMZZZZZZZ_.jpg",
                    "size": "large"
                },
                {
                    "#text": "http://images.amazon.com/images/P/B00005LN6S.01._SCMZZZZZZZ_.jpg",
                    "size": "extralarge"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How to get the url of an image for a given size?

Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: your response is jsonarray name album. So this `jsono = new JSONObject(response);` is not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is nothing but a key-value representation. It's not hard to get a hang of it. Your code should be something like this,

Update: This will only print URL's which have `size = medium`

```
    String response = "{\"album\":[{\"name\":\"DD Y Ponle Play\",\"artist\":\"Jumbo\",\"id\":\"2528039\",\"url\":\"http://www.last.fm/music/Jumbo/DD+Y+Ponle+Play\",\"image\":[{\"#text\":\"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/B00005LN6S.01._SCMZZZZZZZ_.jpg\",\"size\":\"small\"},{\"#text\":\"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/B00005LN6S.01._SCMZZZZZZZ_.jpg\",\"size\":\"medium\"},{\"#text\":\"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/B00005LN6S.01._SCMZZZZZZZ_.jpg\",\"size\":\"large\"},{\"#text\":\"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/B00005LN6S.01._SCMZZZZZZZ_.jpg\",\"size\":\"extralarge\"}]}]}";

    JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray myArray = myObject.getJSONArray( "album" );

    for(int i=0; i<myArray.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject myIterator = myArray.getJSONObject( i );
        JSONArray arrayOne = myIterator.getJSONArray( "image" );

        for(int j=0; j<arrayOne.length(); j++)
        {
            JSONObject myInnerIterator = arrayOne.getJSONObject( j );               
            if(myInnerIterator.has( "size" ))//check if 'size' key is present
                if(myInnerIterator.getString( "size" ).equalsIgnoreCase( "medium" ))
                    System.out.println( myInnerIterator.getString( "#text" ) );
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you I find all the url with your double iteration. But how to get a single size, medium for example?

Comment: If you want to get `size` for a respective `#text`, just use `myInnerIterator.getString( "size" )`;

Comment: But I can not iterate once again because there is no array in myInnerIterrator so JSONArray arrayTwo = myInnerIterator.getJSONArray ("size"); Gives me an exception ... thank you for your patience :)

Comment: Thank you and better solution than mine

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use google GSON for this. Import it as a dependency

First create an album class.

```
public class Albums {

private List<Album> album;

public List<Album> getAlbum() {
    return album;
}

public class Album{
    private String name;
    private String artist;
    private String id;
    private String url;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public List<Image> getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public class Image {
        @SerializedName("#text")
        private String text;
        private String size;

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public String getSize() {
            return size;
        }
    }

    private List<Image> image;
}
```

}

Now in your code where you get the above JSON object try this code below

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

// Im assuming "response" as the above JSON object
Albums albums = gson.fromJson(response.optString("album"),Albums.class);
```

This will map your json to java object.(Note: You can remove unwanted objects from the POJO as you like)

You can get the image using the getter functions

Comment: Albums albums = gson.fromJson(jsono.optString("album"),Albums.class); return null ??

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Raghunandan, you're extracting a JSONObject, when you need to be extracting a JSONArray, and then from that array, you can extract a JSONObject.

Try using a library such as [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to make this task easier, or refer to this tiny JSON library [I wrote](https://github.com/CreativeCodersJosh/AndroidLibrary_JSONParser/blob/master/JSONParser.java).

Comment: This is only an excerpt of the answer ... it is precisely the "array" part. I have coded: jsonArray = jsono.getJSONObject("results").getJSONObject("albummatches").getJSONArray("album");

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple actually to parse a JSON array:

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray("album");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    String url = jsonobject.getString("url");
}
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: There is no "url" in the answer but "#text"

Comment: no, but http://images.amazon.com/images/P/B00005LN6S.01._SCMZZZZZZZ_.jpg

Comment: Oh Sorry I understood your question wrong I was parsing the above url not the image url as answered above by @Parag should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To find the url of the images "medium" I did like this:

```
                            ArrayList<String> listUrl = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject myIterator = null;
                                try {
                                    myIterator = jsonArray.getJSONObject( i );
                                    JSONArray arrayOne = myIterator.getJSONArray( "image" );

                                    for(int j=0; j<arrayOne.length(); j++)
                                    {
                                        JSONObject myInnerIterator = arrayOne.getJSONObject( j );
                                        String s = myInnerIterator.getString( "size" )+myInnerIterator.getString("#text");
                                        if (s.contains("medium") && s.contains("https")){
                                            listUrl.add (s.replace("medium",""));
                                            Log.i("RESPONSE",s.replace("medium",""));
                                        }

                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
```

I think there must be much better ... but it does the job!